# Change displaytag table font size

Tags: html, css, jsp, html-table, displaytag

I am using `displayTag table` to create a table, which is `<d:table></d:table>`, however, I found that the font size of the `<d:column></d:column>` is different with `<d:footer></d:footer>`, which is footer is smaller.

I try to edit it so I try to find it in `displaytag.properties` file, but cant see anything related to the font size.

Following is part of my code and screenshot:

```
<d:column titleKey="finalAmount">
    <fmt:formatNumber value="${row.finalAmount}" pattern="${amountPattern}" />
</d:column>
<d:footer>
    <tr>
        <td >TOTAL</td>
        <td ><fmt:formatNumber value="${principal}" pattern="${amountPattern}" /></td>
    <tr>
</d:footer>
```

[image]

Anyone can tell me where can I do this?

Comment: what CSS property you are using for class `total`? Using a Inspector Tool you can see what css property are used for both..

Comment: hi, sorry, i forget to take out the `class=total`. This class wont affect the font.